# Save re-arranged draggable post items to wordpress database

Tags: posts, post-meta, html5

So i've followed the clearly documented pages for the [packery and the draggabilly plugins](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html) to allow for a customizable grid and looked at how localStorage can be used to remember/store data of the re-arranged order of items upon reload.

So it works fine on the front end, closely following this [example](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/cGhJt).

How would one go about saving this data to a wordpress database? Can one use localstorages data structure to put the updated post order into the db (so mainly a HTML5 and js solution)? Are there any wordpress functions that would aid with this customisation (possibly resulting in more of a PHP solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do the following to save the order data into the WordPress DB,

1. Do a [WordPress AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) sending the data that you want to be stored in it. You can do it at every re-arrange event of the elements.
2. Handle the AJAX call in PHP and either do an [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) or an [update_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) to save the data.